# Converting each entry of each list from string to integer

Tags: python, list, integer

I have lots of lists which contain integers as strings. e.g. `scored_h0=['2','3','4']`. I'm trying to convert each entry of each list from a string to an integer with the code below, but for some reason it's not working. There is no error, it's just when I `print (scored_h0)` (for example) after running the code below, the entries haven't been converted.

```
power_list = [scored_h0, scored_h1, conceded_h0, conceded_h1, scored_a0, scored_a1, conceded_a0, conceded_a1]

for list1 in power_list:
   list1 = list(map(int, list1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are assigning a new value to the variable `list1`, but not mutating the actual array. If you want to mutate all these arrays you'll have to change each value in each of them, like so:

```
for list1 in power_list:
   for i in range(len(list1)):
       list1[i] = int(list1[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
scored_h0 = ['1', '2', '3']
scored_h1 = ['4', '5', '6']
power_list = [scored_h0, scored_h1]

for i in range(len(power_list)):
    for j in range(len(power_list[i])):
        power_list[i][j] = int(power_list[i][j])

print(scored_h0)
print(scored_h1)
```

It prints:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method do the job

```
def to_int(s):
    for l in s:
        for id, val in enumerate(l):
            l[id] = int(val)
```

So you call it as `to_int(power_list)`